# Openshift update java 7 to 8 in Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) Cartridge

Tags: java, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am new to Openshift and i have created a server instance using Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) cartridge for my spring boot web application.

Initially, web application was using JDK7 and was working fine on Openshift. Now for some enhancement we have to switch to JDK8.

I tried searching on Google about changing `JAVA_HOME` to JDK8 and i tried most of the solutions but i can not make it work.

- **Tried Solution 1**: Created `start` file under `app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/` with below content.

  `#!/bin/bash
  export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH`

  Also, the file has `+x` permission.
- **Tried Solution 2**: Created `java8` marker under `app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/markers` and `jbossews/template/.openshift/markers`.

The above solutions don't work. Other option is `DIY` cartridge which may work but i don't want to create new application and move everything there.

**EDIT**

Below is the directory structure

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w1Lj.png)

Please note that i have created this application using open shift UI and not using `rhc` command.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the directory structure of your application repository? The `.openshift/` directory should be in the root folder. Check [this](https://github.com/Athou/commafeed/tree/master/.openshift) repository for example.

Answer (score 3):

I had to "cheat" a little to enable java 8, since the "java8" marker doesn't seem to work. Look at the JbossEWS cartridge source:

```
function export_java_home() {
  if marker_present "java7"; then
    export JAVA_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_JDK7
  else
    export JAVA_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_JDK6
  fi
}
```

So, my solution/workaround is:

- Set your `OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_JDK7` environment var to point to jdk8 instead of jdk7:

```
rhc env set OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_JDK7="/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0" -a YOURAPPNAME
```

- Add the `java7` marker to your `.openshift/markers` directory.

Comment: So basically you're running a custom cartridge?

Comment: No, I was referring to the original JBossEWS cartridge: https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/bin/util

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like bad planning: You're supposed to that your platform supports Java-8 before writing code that requires it. From the Openshift documentation:

> 3.2. Java Environments Supported By JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6
>   JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6 requires Java 6 or Java 7. The list of supported Java environments can be found at http://www.jboss.com/products/platforms/application/supportedconfigurations/. A Java Development Kit (JDK) is required for development, and a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is required to run JBoss Enterprise Application Platform.

Comment: Your answer is not correct: the question is about **Tomcat 6/7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)** cartridge and **NOT** about JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6. The [documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-getting-started.html#_other_markers) clearly states that `Java8` is supported.

Comment: Is that the online version of openshift? Assuming it is, then why not connect into the server directly (ssl) and make the marker and restart the server. Make sure it works first.